# Javafx and Proxy

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

Can a javafx app running on your web page be configured to use a proxy sever, even if the web browser is not configured to use a proxy server

Answer (score 0):

Applications in the browser are usually restricted and can use operations like opening Sockets.

If you have signed application which has wider security permissions you can set proxy settings to it, e.g.:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "my-proxy.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");
```

Comment: So I guess this sounds like a dumb question, do javafx apps need to be signed like java apps to get more access.

Comment: Yes, exactly same way. See http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm

Comment: I know how this question is like how long a piece of string is ?? but how hard is it to get a javafx app signed

Comment: Ive read some of the documentation in getting a app signed, and I think I would have more fun banging my head against a wall for 5 minutes than go through this. It makes getting an ipad app through apple a walk in the park